# MongoDB $pull failing in different ways intermittently

Tags: mongodb

I tried everything. update, updateMany, findOndAndUpdate, findByIdAndUpdate. I want to delete the object that matches the notification id.

indifferent approach it returns me the object, sometimes returns "mongodb cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"
and sometimes "mongodb matchedCount: 1 but modify 0".

This is one of the examples I tried

```
    const userNotifications = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: teacherUpdate.userId}, {
        $pull: { notifications: {_id: notificationId} }
    })
```

My DB:

```
{
"_id": "46df7324d6760d",
"username": "teacher",
"image": null,
"firstname": "Teacher",
"lastname": "Killer",
"skills": null,
"teacher": {
"teacherId": "046e2734d6260dc6"
},
"student": null,
"email": "teacher@gmail.com",
"activeSession": false,
"__v": 1,
"notifications": [
{
"type": "Lesson request",
"content": {
"date": "8.25",
"time": "10",
"status": "Pending",
"studentId": "d03d3c6d0085",
"teacherId": "2732d6286dc6"
},
"_id": "f9659d128c297f85",
"__v": 0
},
{
"type": "Lesson request",
"content": {
"date": "8.26",
"time": "08",
"status": "Pending",
"studentId": "8b4d3d3f8f3485",
"teacherId": "6e273246286d9c6"
},
"_id": "9659d1128c8b",
"__v": 0
}
]
},
```

Comment: _"mongodb cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"_ - you probably have some documents with `"notifications"` as non-array field. (2) _"mongodb matchedCount: 1 but modify 0"_ - this mostly means that there is matched document but the data is not updated as the data to be changed is same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UserModel.update(
    { '_id': teacherUpdate.userId }, 
    { $pull: { notifications: { _id: notificationId } } },
    false, // Upsert
    true, // Multi
);
```

**Edit**

this should work

```
let updatedUser = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': teacherUpdate.userId },  { $pull: { notifications: { _id: notificationId } } }, {
      new: true
    });
```

Comment: It returns me this error - 
errorMessage: "Callback must be a function, got true"

Comment: please check updated code.

Comment: I tried this also and now it returns the whole user object.
I rechecked all the id's values and everything is correct